# compute $H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$-norm for smooth $u$ and $\Omega$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am a little bit confused about different definitions of the trace space $H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)$, and I hope I can find some simple examples on how to explicitly compute these norms for simple geometries.

For example, let $u:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function on a sufficiently smooth domain $\Omega$, say $\Omega=B_R(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, such that the traces of its value and its derivatives equal to themselves.  May I know how to explicitly compute the norm $\|u\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)}$ on the circle $\partial \Omega=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=R^2\}$? I know for sufficiently smooth $u$, the norm can be defined as 
$$
\|u\|^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)}=\int_{\partial\Omega} |u|^2\,dS+\int_{\partial \Omega} \sum_{i=1}^2 |\partial_i u|^2\,dS+ \sum_{i=1}^2 \int_{\partial \Omega}\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{|\partial_i u(x)-\partial_i u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}\,dS_xdS_y,
$$
where $dS_x$ is the boundary measure. But what do these $\partial_iu$ mean? Is it simply the derivatives of $u$ on $\Omega$ restricted on $\partial \Omega$? I thought the definition of $\partial_i$ must involve the geometry of the domain.

Comment: I guess for this You need the trace operator.

Comment: @PeterMelech But I assume $u$ to be a sufficiently smooth function, to avoid the technical trace operator.

Comment: In this case You assume $u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ ,i.e. the partial derivatives have continuous extensions up to the boundary? Then it should be clear what $\partial_i u$ mean.

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes. I assume $u$ is continuously differentiable up to boundary. Then in this case, may I know what does $\partial_i u$ mean in the definition of $H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: Yes, I think so, anyway the geometry of the domain is involved somehow if You assume the partial derivatives to have continuous extensions up to the boundary.